# How to place 2 <div>'s next to eachother instead of below eachother in Blazor SyncFusion Card Component?

Tags: html, css, blazor, title, syncfusion

I'm using the Card component in SyncFusion blazor, this component has a title and a subtitle property. In default situation those are placed below eachother:

[image]

The following css is used:

Title:

[image]

Sub title:

[image]

However I'm trying to place these items next to eachother like this:

[image]

Does anyone know the right css for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like you could do .e-card-header-caption { display: flex; flex-direction: row; } and they will be next to eachother but it is hard to say without some html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify **display : inline** for **e-card-header-title** and **e-card-sub-title** class in css style to display title and subtitle in same row.

**Snippet**

```
.e-card .e-card-header .e-card-header-caption .e-card-header-title {
   display: inline;
 }
.e-card .e-card-header .e-card-header-caption .e-card-sub-title {
   display: inline;
 }
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Sample**
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Subtitle1482508206.zip

Thanks,
Durga G

Answer (score 1):

```
.e-card-header-caption { display: flex; flex-direction: row; }
```

Comment: Please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer to provide more detail. Specifically, it would be helpful if you explained how this solves the problem - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26662494)